# How to make a value in picklist default for a particular page layout

Tags: picklist

I want to make a value in picklist field for a custom page layout as default which I tried to do for that field but that did not work.

Comment: do you have record types for that object & does that page layout tied to a particular record type / profile ?

Comment: Thanks buddy,I figured out,actually I was making changes in page layout and not on the record type.I made changes and made the particular field as default and it worked.Thanks buddy